# Docker Perl Sublimetext3 development setup

Tags: macos, perl, docker

I am setting up a perl development environment for the first time in a number of years I want to leverage docker and sublime text plus I run on MAC OSX.

I wanted to use Docker to create a dev env that i could share with others on my team.
I like SublimeText and integration with PerlCritic.
I understand about host mounted volumes to allow me to edit locally and save on the docker container.
What I cant work out is how to avoid installing all the perl dependencies on my MAC to enable Sublime to have access to them and allow the sublime perl critic integration to function.

Is it possible to :-

a) Install the complete perl environment in a docker container (this much i know is true)
b) Use SublimeText on my MAC such that all the Sublime Plugins continue to work from the dependencies in the container?

I also understand that Sublime Text has build plugins for perl but from what i understand that occurs at build time not whilst developing - thus still requiring dependencies locally on the MAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that you could have your perl install on a mounted docker volume (as you suggested)

Then in the container do

```
perl -V
```

which amongst other things will give you

```
  @INC:
    /usr/local/lib64/perl5
    /usr/local/share/perl5
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    .
```

From your Mac you can then use the PERL5LIB environment to add these to the search path. Ideally these will all be in your mount point. The lib64 sections will not work as these are compiled modules.

```
export PERL5LIB=/my/docker/mount/perl/lib:/my/docker/mount/lib2
```

You will probably only need the share sections

I would also match the perl version on the Mac to the docker version by using [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/). This is also available in `perl -V`

Just as a general rule, never mess with the Mac Perl standard install as it causes many problems as the OS uses it for things